# How to use passportSocketIo and socketioJwt in io.use

Tags: node.js, api, socket.io, jwt, passport.js

Hi i'm trying to authenticated sockets connection using passportSocketIo and socketioJwt, the first one it's been used for web purpose and the second one for API auth, passportSocketIo works fine, but 
 how can i make this middleware (io.use) chooses socketioJwt if i send JWT or passportSocketIo, the reason is that i don't know how to set up the middleware, i have some  like this:

```
let express =                    require('express');
let app =                                 express();
let http =        require('http').createServer(app);
let socket =              require('socket.io')(http);
const cookieparser =        require('cookie-parser');
const session =           require('express-session');
const passport =                 require('passport');
const passportSocketIo =require("passport.socketio");
const socketioJwt   =        require("socketio-jwt");
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);


let io = require('./helpers/Socket.js').listen(http);


app.use(session({
  key: 'connect.sid',
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    store: sessionStore
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
    passport : passport,
    cookieParser: cookieparser,        // the same middleware you registrer in express
    key:          'connect.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express/connect stores its session_id
    secret:       'secret',    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
    store:        sessionStore,        // we NEED to use a sessionstore. no memorystore please
    success:      onAuthorizeSuccess,  // *optional* callback on success - read more below
    fail:         onAuthorizeFail,     // *optional* callback on fail/error - read more below
  }),socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: 'jwt_secret',
    handshake: true
  }));
```

Socket.js

```
let app =                      require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
var socket = require('socket.io')
const Order = require('../models/Order')
const User = require('../models/User')

const { isLoggedIn } = require('../helpers/Auth');


module.exports.listen = function(http) {
    io = socket.listen(http)


    io.on('connection', async (socket, req) => {
        socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Connected to app' });

        //get socketId
        console.log('connected: ',socket.request.user.facebook.name);
        const socketId = socket.id;
        //get userId
        const id = socket.request.user;
        //LookUp userId and save/update socketId in to User
        const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( id, {socketId} );



        socket.on('disconnect', async() => {

        //get socketId
        const socketId = null;
        //get userId
        const id = socket.request.user;
        //LookUp userId and update socketId from User
        const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( id, {socketId} );

            console.log('Se desconectó:', user.facebook.name);
        });




        socket.on('status',  async function(data) {

        // Destructure data
            const {status, _id, userId} = data;
        // Look Up Order bt id
            const orden = await Order.findByIdAndUpdate  ( _id, { status  });
        // Look Up User by id
            const user   = await User.findById( {_id : userId});
        //Set the socketId in to emit event
        if(user.socketId === null){console.log('User Not available')}
        else{
            socket.to(user.socketId).emit( 'status_updated', orden )
            console.log(data);
            }
        });
   }

   );


    console.log('in socket');









    return io
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i've searched and i found that i must to use two end points socket, one for passport using cookies and anoher one with jwt so i hav to add a new file using socket

```
let io = require('./helpers/Socket.js').listen(http);
let io2 = require('./helpers/Socket_Jwt.js').listen(http);

io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
    passport : passport,
    cookieParser: cookieparser,        // the same middleware you registrer in express
    key:          'connect.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express/connect stores its session_id
    secret:       'secret',    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
    store:        sessionStore,        // we NEED to use a sessionstore. no memorystore please
    success:      onAuthorizeSuccess,  // *optional* callback on success - read more below
    fail:         onAuthorizeFail,     // *optional* callback on fail/error - read more below
  }));
io2.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: 'jwt_secret',
    handshake: true
  })
```

socket_jwt.js

```
var socket = require('socket.io')



module.exports.listen = function(http) {
    io2 = socket.listen(http)


 io.on('connection', async (socket, req) => {
        socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Connected to api' });
}

    return io2
}
```